# Integrating Quickblox Android SDK for Chat

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm trying to integrate the chat service of [quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Login_to_Chat) in my application, i manage to add all the libraries all the needed classes and layouts but when i run i get a java.lang.NullPointerException in this line :

```
int currentVersion = ApplicationSingleton.getInstance().getAppVersion();
```

and i get this error

```
   Caused by: vc908.stickerfactory.p$b: Storage manager not initialized. Use init(...) method before.
            at vc908.stickerfactory.p.a(Unknown Source)
            at vc908.stickerfactory.utils.KeyboardUtils.getKeyboardHeight(Unknown Source)
            at com.superfans.com.superfans.chat.ui.activities.ChatActivity.updateStickersFrameParams(ChatActivity.java:278)
            at com.superfans.com.superfans.chat.ui.activities.ChatActivity.initViews(ChatActivity.java:184)
            at com.superfans.com.superfans.chat.ui.activities.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:83)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

in this line :

```
  stickersFrame.getLayoutParams().height = vc908.stickerfactory.utils.KeyboardUtils.getKeyboardHeight();
```

can any one help and thnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Stickers) guide about stickers integration

looks like you forgot about

```
StickersManager.initialize(“847b82c49db21ecec88c510e377b452c", this);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but my problem was in adding the provider in the manifest  android:authorities="<YOUR PACKAGE>.stickersProvider"